# RecyclerView crea un registro fantasma al eliminar

Tags: android, sqlite, recyclerview, cursor

Tengo un problema al eliminar un elemento de mi *RecyclerView* (el cual está enlazado a una base de datos *SQLite*). Después de eliminar correctamente el dato tanto de la base de datos como de la vista, se muestra la animación de eliminado, pero después aparece un nuevo elemento al final, también con una bonita animación.

Al comprobar la base de datos veo que el registro en cuestión sí que está eliminado.

Podría solucionar esto instanciando un adaptador nuevo cada vez que elimino un registro, pero entonces la animación no se muestra.

Código:

Método del *Adapter*:

```
public void removeItem(int position){
    db = new DBAdapter(context);
    db.open();
    mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
    int idnota = mCursorAdapter.getCursor().getInt(0);
    db.borra_nota(idnota); //it deletes the row (delete_note)
    db.close();
}
```

*Main Activity*:

```
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    //if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {

    listAdapter.removeItem(position);
    listAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, listAdapter.getItemCount());
    listAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

La solución cutre (sin animación) pasaba a ser algo así:

```
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    sticky = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lista_notas);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    sticky.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    sticky.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

En cuyo caso, pasaría los `removeItem` y demás dentro del *Adapter*.

¿Alguna solución para que al borrarse el registro, la animación se muestre correctamente y además no cree un registro fantasma al final?

Answer (score 0):

Vale, solucionado...

El problema residía en que estaba eliminando de todos sitios menos del *CursorAdapter* en sí.

El método del *ListAdapter* queda ahora así, funcionando correctamente:

```
    public void removeItem(int position){
        db = new DBAdapter(context);
        db.open();
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
        int idnota = mCursorAdapter.getCursor().getInt(0);
        db.borra_nota(idnota); //it deletes the row (delete_note)

        items = db.consulta_todos(); //select all from db again
        mCursorAdapter.changeCursor(items);
    }
```

Saludos, espero que sea útil a quien se haya topado con mi problema.